# Utilizing a transparent image from my laptop

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm stuck with a weird situation and I'm not entirely sure how to make this work. I edited an image in photoshop to a certain shape and saved it as a PNG, when I save that image to Flickr to import it into the webpage Im currently building Flickr converts the transparent background white thereby rendering the image useless. Is there an image hosting website that won't convert my png to jpg and fill the background white? If not is there a way to import the image directly from my device to use it in my HTML code? I've included the image so you can have an idea about what I'm referring to. Any help would be greatly appreciated! https://flic.kr/p/23F8D2t

Comment: Why would you use Flickr as image host instead of your own server?

Comment: As @rolfv1 mentioned, you should host the image on your own server for consistency. secondly if you click on `download` and click on `original` you will get your transparent image. you would want to hack a solution with that link it is something like this: `//farm5.staticflickr.com/4705/39824239761_8c59b1ab52_o_d.png` (exaclty it does not makes much sense)

Comment: Thanks for your response, to be honest I'm just starting out in web development and right now I'm working on a challenge for FreeCodeCamp. To stylize the project and to go a bit beyond what the project parameters require I'm trying to figure this out, it'll be a) good practice for future projects and b) just trying to give myself a further challenge. With that said I don't really know how to build my own server, hence why I was using Flickr.

Comment: If you want the images to be saved temporarily, you can use [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation) or [mega.nz](https://mega.nz/dev). These are hosting services and will provide you will a shareable link, or you can use the developer api to retrieve and fetch the images (even save them directly).